# Android text selection toolbar is not showing up while using SelectionContainer in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

I want to create selectable text using Jetpack Compose. Sample code is as following

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TextSelectionTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    SelectionContainer(){
        Text(text = "Hello This is a sample text for testing out selections $name!")
    }

}
```

The problem is, it is showing only copy button near selection.

[image]

but when I use normal text view with `isSelectable = true`, it shows Android text selection toolbar,

[image]

Need help to understand how to show such toolbar in Jetpack compose when some text is selected and also is it possible to show More custom options ?

Comment: I think you should [create](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) a feature request on compose issue tracker, right now such customisation doesn't seems to be supported.